# Copy output of commands to a file but make them believe they are writing in a terminal

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

To copy the output of my commands launched from a shell I use

```
exec > >(tee myfile)
```

and then the next commands will be logged into the file.

The problem is the commands know the output is not a terminal anymore. So they can change how they display. For instance, with the command `ls` when the redirection is on, the output is displayed in only one column.

I know I can use `unbuffer` when I use a pipe, but it is not what I want. I want to be able to log all the outputs I have from my shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `script`, which copies all output to a file (usually `typescript`).  It does not interfere with the program, allowing it to think it is writing to the terminal.

The program is available "everywhere", though some options differ:

- [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) Linux
- [script(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html) OSX

The main difference that I encounter is how to specify the output filename and the command.  With Linux you can give a command as an option, while in OSX the command consists of the argument(s) past the filename.  When using the `-c` option on Linux, keep in mind that `script` runs this using the shell identified by the `SHELL` environment variable.  That can actually be "any" program (I've used a text editor).  Running a shell to execute a command means that it may use new environment variables (normally not a problem).

If you do not use the `-c` option, `script` starts a new shell, writing everything to its output until you exit from that shell.  To use it as you were doing for redirection, you could make an alias like

```
alias redir=`script myfile'
```

to *write* to *myfile*, or

```
alias redir='script -a myfile'
```

to *append* to *myfile*.  In either case, exiting the shell (press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, or type `exit`) will end the "redirection".

[image]

Aside from `ls` (which ignores the terminal database), most programs use the `TERM` environment variable.  It is possible that you do something unusual in initializing your shell, so that running `script` would reinitialize `TERM` to a *different* value than you are currently using.  To see this, you could do something like

```
env >before.log
script -c "env >after.log"
diff before.log after.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I did not know _script_. It addresses the problem exposed here, but unfortunately not my whole problem since I cannot use it in the same way I used _exec > >(tee myfile)_... And when I use _script -c_, _ls_ loses the colors.

Comment: I know the _color_ option for _ls_. It was just to show that it is not the same as without the _script_ command. It won't work for all commands.