# How to unbuffer and capture output of LFTP EOF command?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stdout, lftp

I have the following command to mirror some files with LFTP:

```
unbuffer lftp $PROTOCOL://$URL -u ${USER},${PASS} << EOF > ${LOGSTDOUT}
set dns:fatal-timeout never
set sftp:auto-confirm yes
set mirror:use-pget-n 50
set mirror:parallel-transfer-count 2
set mirror:parallel-directories yes
set mirror:include-regex $REGEX
set log:enabled/xfer yes
set log:file/xfer $LOG
set xfer:use-temp-file yes
set xfer:temp-file-name *.lftp
mirror -c -v --loop --Remove-source-dirs "$REMOTEDIR" "$LOCALDIR"
quit
EOF
```

I am trying to capture the output of this command. I already output to a log file using xfer, but this sadly doesn't show the handy progress % that I desire.

Any thoughts? My above attempt with unbuffer is unsuccessful.

Comment: Does the progress % display at all (like on your screen, rather than go to file)? When I have accidentally captured progress information to a log file, it is **always** in a very messy state filled with ANSI control chars that are used to create the animation/overwriting at the same position. It will be a headache to use that once it is in a file (IMHO). Good luck!

Comment: The file just has this one line: [?2004hlftp user@server:~>

Comment: Yes, it definitely might be very messy, but I can't even see that messy output to make a decision. If there is a better solution with lftp/xfer to get the % logged, I'm also open to that.

Comment: *"The file just has this one line:"* ..  That sounds like it is in interactive mode. Look for an `lftp` option to turn interactive mode off. (Not a regular `lftp` user). .... Hmm ... *"better solution ... to get the % logged"*, you want to write a script that uses `%` status?? Really Good luck. (-;!

Comment: The widely-available [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) utility might be useful.  See [Copy output of commands to a file but make them believe they are writing in a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35522759/4154375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @pjh I have come to the following solution using `script`:

```
env TERM=dumb script -a $LOGSTDOUT -c "$(cat <<- EOF
    lftp $PROTOCOL://$URL -u ${USER},${PASS} << EOFF
    set dns:fatal-timeout never
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 50
    set mirror:parallel-transfer-count 2
    set mirror:parallel-directories yes
    set mirror:include-regex $REGEX
    set log:enabled/xfer yes
    set log:file/xfer $LOG
    set xfer:use-temp-file yes
    set xfer:temp-file-name *.lftp
    mirror -c -v --loop --Remove-source-dirs "$REMOTEDIR" "$LOCALDIR"
    quit
    EOFF
EOF
)"
```

The `env TERM=dumb` is a random line I found that removes ANSI escape codes from the output to file.